# Qt Creator cannot find library with custom cmake step

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cmake, qt-creator

In Qt Creator (version 3.0.1, with Qt version 5.2.1), I have made a custom `cmake` step (instead of `qmake`), with the following `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

add_executable (myapp source.cpp)

target_link_libraries(myapp dl)
```

In my `source.cpp` file, I have the following code:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main()
{
    dlopen("mylibrary.so", RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL);
    return 0;
}
```

And `mylibrary.so` is located in `/usr/lib`.

When I compile this using `cmake` and `make` from the command line, it compiles as expected. However, if I try to build this in Qt Creator, I receive the following error:

```
undefined reference to `dlopen'
```

This suggests that Qt Creator does not know where to look to find `libdl.so`, which is in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

So my question is: Why does running `cmake` and `make` from the command line work, whereas building in Qt Creator does not work? And how do I tell Qt Creator where to search for `libdl.so`?

Comment: Which target are you using in QtCreator?

Comment: Btw, cmake 2.8 is very old. Please upgrade.

Comment: You can use `CMAKE_DL_LIBS` variable. It is a built-in variable, that hold path to dl library.  http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_DL_LIBS.html

Comment: @jet47: It does not hold the whole path, unfortunately; that is for the name. The OP has issues with the path. See yourself: `message("TEST:${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")`.

Comment: It is not solved. The only solution I have so far is to use the whole path: `target_link_libraries(myapp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `QLibrary` in Qt software for dealing with dynamic loading, lookup and the like. You would also spare the hassle that you are seeing now.

Secondly, you can use this, but it is a bit hard-wiring things, admittedly:

```
target_link_libraries(myapp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so)
```

Thirdly, the even better approach would be to use some find module for this as follows:

```
# - Find libdl
# Find the native LIBDL includes and library
#
# LIBDL_INCLUDE_DIR - where to find dlfcn.h, etc.
# LIBDL_LIBRARIES - List of libraries when using libdl.
# LIBDL_FOUND - True if libdl found.
IF (LIBDL_INCLUDE_DIR)
# Already in cache, be silent
SET(LIBDL_FIND_QUIETLY TRUE)
ENDIF (LIBDL_INCLUDE_DIR)
FIND_PATH(LIBDL_INCLUDE_DIR dlfcn.h)
SET(LIBDL_NAMES dl libdl ltdl libltdl)
FIND_LIBRARY(LIBDL_LIBRARY NAMES ${LIBDL_NAMES} )
# handle the QUIETLY and REQUIRED arguments and set LIBDL_FOUND to TRUE if
# all listed variables are TRUE
INCLUDE(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(LibDL DEFAULT_MSG LIBDL_LIBRARY LIBDL_INCLUDE_DIR)
IF(LIBDL_FOUND)
SET( LIBDL_LIBRARIES ${LIBDL_LIBRARY} )
ELSE(LIBDL_FOUND)
SET( LIBDL_LIBRARIES )
ENDIF(LIBDL_FOUND)
MARK_AS_ADVANCED( LIBDL_LIBRARY LIBDL_INCLUDE_DIR )
```

and then you can find it as follows given that you have it in your cmake module path:

```
find_package(LIBDL REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Is QLibrary the *only* way to solve this? Or just the recommended way?

Comment: @Karnivaurus: I would recommended that; failing that, the find_package(LIBDL REQUIRED) way. But each way works as long as you are happy with them. I would be the happiest with QLibrary personally unless it would take me too much time to rewrite.

Comment: @Karnivaurus: any reason for not having selected an answer?